# Postgres Sharding with Patitioning on Primary key

Tags: postgresql, partitioning, sharding

for Partitioning (Postgres Version 12) I have referred below link.
The only change I added is Primary Key.

https://severalnines.com/database-blog/how-configure-postgresql-sharding-clustercontrol

```
CREATE TABLE shardschema.department (
    id      int8,
    version integer,
    name varchar,
    age    varchar,
    sal integer,
    CONSTRAINT department_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
    )partition by range(id)
;
```

```
CREATE TABLE shardschema.department_210101 PARTITION
OF shardschema.department FOR VALUES FROM 
('2101010000000000000') TO('2108319999999999999') ;
```

```
CREATE FOREIGN  TABLE shardschema.department_210901 
PARTITION OF shardschema.department FOR VALUES FROM 
('2109010000000000000') TO('2112319999999999999')
server shard_13;
```

ERROR:  cannot create foreign partition of partitioned table "department"
DETAIL:  Table "department" contains indexes that are unique.
SQL state: 42809

Any Solution on this problem ? Thanks in Advance

Comment: "*Any solution on this problem?*"  - remove the primary key?

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this error is that PostgreSQL cannot guarantee uniqueness on a foreign table.

You should drop the primary key on the partitioned table and instead create a primary key on each partition. Because you partitioned the table by the primary key column, that will automatically guarantee global uniqueness.

Comment: removed PK, and tried creating PK on partition table , but still gives same error.

Comment: Can't be. If you drop all unique and primary key constraints on `department`, it cannot tell you `Table "department" contains indexes that are unique.`